# Who is the producer that produced the invalid block?

Tags: block-producer

Few questions about the blockchain freeze in 16/06/2018:

1. Who is the producer that produced the invalid block?
2. Why was it not tested during the testing period?
3. Were tests added to EOSIO to test the case where another producer produce an invalid block?
4. Shouldn't that block be ignored and the BPs who produced it be automatically voted out? (until he will fix that issue at least)

Comment: 1. and 2. is not of importance, I think.
3. There is an open issue that requests more unit tests: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4159